# Dar estilo a una celda de un DataTable en PrimeFaces

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Tengo un problema que no puedo resolver.

Un componente `<p:dataTable>` de Primefaces renderiza una tabla **HTML** en el navegador, lo que necesito es poner un color de fondo al elemento `<td>` de la tabla **HTML**, esto por cuestiones de diseño cada celda representa un elemento que tiene un estado que se identifica con un color (verde, amarillo, café, rojo).

La página es la siguiente

```
<p:dataTable var="categoria" value="#{divisionBean.categorias}" styleClass="tablaP8TPrime">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Alimentos
    </f:facet>
    <p:column headerText="Categoría">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.nombre}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna1}">
        <h:panelGroup id="celda" layout="block">
            <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(0).getNombre()}" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna2}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(1).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna3}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(2).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna4}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(3).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna5}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(4).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna6}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(5).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna7}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(6).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna8}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(7).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna9}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(8).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna10}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(9).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna11}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(10).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna12}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(11).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna13}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(12).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna14}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(13).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna15}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(14).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna16}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(15).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna17}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(16).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna18}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(17).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna19}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(18).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna20}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(19).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna21}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(20).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna22}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(21).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna23}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(22).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna24}">
        <h:outputText value="#{categoria.automovil.get(23).getNombre()}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Los datos se llenan correctamente, ahora lo que necesito es poner dichos colores.

Comment: ¿Cuál celda necesitas poner el color? ¿Y de acuerdo a qué cambiará el color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No me queda claro si hablas de una celda en cualquier columna o sólo las celdas de una columna. En cualquier caso, puedes usar una expresión en EL en el atributo `styleClass` de cada columna:

```
<p:column headerText="#{divisionBean.columna1}" styleClass="#{categoria.automovil.get(0).getNombre() eq 'Blanco' ? 'estiloBlanco' : 'estiloNegro'}">
```

En tu caso, con cuatro posibles valores y con una EL tan larga, te sugeriría que añadieras una propiedad al bean (por ejemplo, `getEstiloColumna`), para poner allí la lógica de qué estilo usar. También puedes definir una función de JSTL, para hacer eso mismo, si te va mejor.